# How exactly does this completion handler work?

Tags: swift, closures, swift5, completionhandler

I've done some research on closures, closures that receive parameters, trailing closures, and completion handlers, but I'm having difficulty understanding when the two arguments to completion, manager and file are passed. In the pick() function definition, there is nowhere in the function scope that calls the completion with completion(manager, file) syntax. There is, however, a present method and I think I am missing something about present() that may include the call for the completion closure with proper arguments. I would appreciate your help.

```
public func pick(from vc: UIViewController?, withCompletion completion: @escaping (_ manager: HSDriveManager?, _ file: GTLRDrive_File?) -> Void) {
        viewer?.completion = completion
        viewer?.shouldSignInOnAppear = true
        
        //As of now, present() seems to include the calling of the completion closure.
        //self is the HSDriverPicker class
        print(type(of: self))
        vc?.present(self, animated: true)
        
    }
```

The code below is the function call for pick. What confuses me is that in order for manager and file to act like arguments of the completion closure somewhere in the function call there has be a part that passes those arguments. I don't see them. I would appreciate your insight on what exactly the present method does and whether it takes care of calling the closure with necessary arguments.

```
picker.pick(from: self) {
                (manager, file) in

                print("picked file: \(file?.name ?? "-none-")")

                let destinationPath = "/Users/james/Desktop/tests"
                
                manager!.downloadFile(file!, toPath: destinationPath, withCompletionHandler: {
                    error in

                    if error != nil {
                        print("Error downloading : \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                    }
                    else {
                        print("Success downloading to : \(destinationPath)")
                    }
                })
            }
```

Comment: See the line `viewer?.completion = completion`? That indicates that `pick` isn't responsible for calling the completion handler. `viewer` (whatever that is) _is_.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you so much. I'll check the codes that belong to viewer.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but the closure syntax with underscore character and parameter label has been abandoned in Swift 3. This is sufficient: `@escaping (HSDriveManager?, GTLRDrive_File?) -> Void`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `present(_:animated:)` won't be responsible for calling the completion closure. `viewer?.completion = completion` means `viewer` will take care of calling the completion closure in its scope(that's why `@escaping` is used, i.e the closure will outlive the scope that you've passed it to). The two arguments `manager` and `file` aren't supposed to be passed by the client but are exposed to the client so that whoever calls the `picker.pick` could use these properties and perform the certain action that will then called inside `viewer`. The closure with parameters simply means the client could use that parameter without worrying about who and when will those parameters be passed.